# Mouse handling for overlapping SVG elements not working as expected

Tags: javascript, svg, path, hover, mouse

I have several SVG path elements, each of which is inside a parent svg element, like so:

```
<svg class="connector" style="position:absolute;left:277.5px;top:65px" position="absolute" pointer-events:"none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" height="152.5px" width="410.015625px">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 149.5 410.015625 149.5" id="path1"></path>
</svg>

<svg style="position:absolute;left:277.5px;top:109px" position="absolute" pointer-events:"none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" height="108.5px" width="410.015625px">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#880000" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 105.5 410.015625 105.5" id="path2"></path>
</svg>
```

The svg elements (and thus their child paths) are visually overlapping.

I want to have a hover effect, so I've setup a mouseenter and mouseleave event on each of the paths.

When the mouse is overtop of an area that doesn't overlap, the hovering works as expected, however, when the mouse is over top of an area where the bounding rects of the svg elements overlap, the mouse events are not triggered correctly.

If, however, I place the same two path elements into a single svg as shown below, then the mouse hovering works as expected, even where the bounding rectangles overlap.

```
<svg class="connector" style="position:absolute;left:277.5px;top:265px" position="absolute" pointer-events:"none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" height="152.5px" width="410.015625px">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 149.5 410.015625 149.5" id="path3"></path>

  <path fill="none" stroke="#008800" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 105.5 410.015625 105.5" id="path4"></path>
</svg>
```

### JSFiddle

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVrLx/4/) showing the two cases.  The red lines are in separate svg elements and the green lines are in a single svg element.  The green lines work as I expect.  The red lines do not.

### Notes

- The paths only look different because the two SVG elements had different "top" attributes in the first example.
- Some similar questions mention the need to set pointer-events, but I think I've got those set correctly (to none on the svg element, and to visibleStroke on the paths).

### Question

How can I make the mouse handle of the first case, with two svg elements, behave the same way as for the second case with a single svg element?

Comment: This does not really answer your question, but is it really necessary to have them in separate svg elements? I'd suggest using `transform="translate(x, y)"` to replace the CSS `left` and `top`, and put them in one <svg> to get the 'native' `pointer-events`, if possible, as that seems to work like a charm in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @Oscar I may end up doing that, however, the mouse handling in some similar code we have that uses jsplumb for the connecting lines works properly with the paths in separate svg elements.  I mimicked everything I could see from the jsplumb svg & path elements, but it still doesn't behave the same way.  I must know why! :-)

Comment: I understand the frustration ;) Good to see the solution has been found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding pointer-events="none" with the correct syntax (you are using a : instead of an =) to the svg on top seems to work for me at least on Firefox. Like so...

```
<svg class="connector" style="position:absolute;left:277.5px;top:65px" height="152.5px" width="410.015625px">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 149.5 410.015625 149.5" id="path1"></path>
</svg>

<svg style="position:absolute;left:277.5px;top:109px;" pointer-events="none" height="108.5px" width="410.015625px">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#880000" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 105.5 410.015625 105.5" id="path2"></path>
</svg>

<svg class="connector" style="position:absolute;left:277.5px;top:265px" position="absolute" height="152.5px" width="410.015625px">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 149.5 410.015625 149.5" id="path3"></path>

  <path fill="none" stroke="#008800" stroke-width="6" pointer-events="visibleStroke" d="M0 3C100 3 310.015625 105.5 410.015625 105.5" id="path4"></path>
```

Comment: Oh ma gurd!  Thanks for spotting that!  It's working properly now in my actual app.

Comment: You know that thing where you are certain that your problem is not "X", so you stop looking at "X", but your problem is actually "X".  Yeah...that. :-|